# При создании формы не передается нужный список под select [django forms]

Tags: python, django

Надо вывести в форму select все поля module_name из базы. Почему из базы выборка не происходит?

**forms.py**

```
class PluginForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Plugins
        fields = ['module_name',]
        widgets = {
            'module_name': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

**views.py**

```
class ViewCurrentPlugins(DetailView):
    model = Plugins
    template_name = 'plugins/plugins_detail_view.html'
    context_object_name = 'plugins_item'

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = RelatedPluginForm()
        print('context form ',context['form'])
        return context
```

**вывод print**

```
<tr><th><label for="id_module_name">Имя модуля:</label></th><td><select name="module_name" class="form-control" maxlength="150" id="id_module_name">
</select></td></tr>
```

**UPD**

**models.py**

```
class Plugins(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Название')       
    module_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, verbose_name='Имя модуля')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('view_current_plugins', kwargs={'pk': self.pk, 'tag':'show'})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        return super(Plugins, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Плагин'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Плагины'
        ordering = ['title']
```

Comment: Как ответил Py_DG проблема возможно в отсутствии queryset,покажите пожалуйста вашу модель.

Answer (score 0):

Я могу быть не прав, потому как только учусь Джанге, так что не судите строго.

```
class ViewCurrentPlugins(DetailView):

    model = Plagins
    form = PluginForm
    queryset = Plugins.objects.all()
    context_object_name = 'plugins'
    template_name = 'plugin_detail_view.html'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'slug'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['plugins'] = self.plugins

        return context
```

В целом, мне кажется проблема в отсутствии объявления кверисета queryset = Plugins.objects.all().
Я не очень хорош в работе с формами, так что еще раз, не судите строго и буду рад объективной критике))